# Subdomain is unexpectedly resolving despite Nginx not being set up to reverse proxy it

Tags: nginx, proxy, dns, cloudflare

So I have been setting up my home network to host a few websites under a domain (and it's subdomains) using a combination of cloudflare to proxy and provide DDoS protection/HTTPS to the sites, and an Nginx reverse proxy running on my network to allow multiple sites to return from behind the same gateway that the DNS records in cloudflare are pointed at.

For the purposes of this explanation, I will replace my real domain name with [domainNameHere].

The first thing to explain is my DNS setup on cloudflare.

I have 4 `CNAME` records setup to do the following:

*Note that I'm using `CNAME` records because I do not have a static home IP, therefore I'm using a Dynamic DNS address that resolves to the IP address of my gateway. This same Dynamic DNS address is used in place of an A record as I'm aiming to not need to update A records all the time, and instead just have it resolve via a automatically updating Dynamic DNS record.*

1. `[domainNameHere].net` - Reverse proxy returns the root site when this domain is requested.
2. `www.[domainNameHere].net` - Behaves the same as the above, just there to handle any www requests, the reverse proxy returns the same root site for both `wwww` and the root domain name.
3. `map.[domainNameHere].net` - When this subdomain of `[domainNameHere]` is called, the reverse proxy instead returns a different site (a map, as you might have guessed).
4. `test.[domainNameHere].net` - This is a proxied DNS record setup in cloudflare for future purposes, I do not yet intend for it to actually return a site.

Now, the expected behaviour is that all of these DNS records should currently return a site, expect for `test.[domainNameHere].net` which shouldn't - I'd expect it to just return a standard `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` like any other DNS record that doesn't actually go anywhere.

Instead though, when `test.[domainNameHere].net` is used, it returns the root site that `[domainNameHere].net` and `www.[domainNameHere].net` resolve to?

Using `map`, `www` or the root domain name all return the expected content.

I believe that I have configured something incorrectly in the Nginx settings, below are the two configuration files that are currently in my `sites-enabled` directory:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name [domainNameHere].net www.[domainNameHere].net;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name test.[domainNameHere].net;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://jake-server:8123;
        }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my Nginx setup? I thought the behaviour would be that if I haven't setup `test.[domainNameHere].net` within Nginx, then it wouldn't resolve on the reverse proxy and therefore wouldn't return anything, or would just return the Nginx 404/403 page?

Is it maybe something to do with how the first setup file is setup to point to local files on the proxy, rather than using `proxy_pass` like is usually done in a reverse proxy?

Or is this not an issue with Nginx, and is an issue with how I've set Cloudflare up?

Comment: `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` means there is no DNS record, but there is one, and it points to the server. The server will use the default `server` to respond to requests which do not match a `server_name`. See [how Nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for details.

Comment: can you please post a list of entries in cloudflare's "DNS" tab.  You should have something like:
[domainNameHere].net CNAME <dynamic dns hostname> PROXIED,
www.[domainNameHere].net CNAME <dynamic dns hostname> PROXIED,
map.[domainNameHere].net CNAME <dynamic dns hostname> PROXIED.

  There should be no entry for test.[domainNameHere].net there

Comment: @RichardSmith Thank you for the link, it seems the most appropriate thing for me to do then, would be to make a setup that returns a 444 or some other error code when the test domain is used - I will reply and answer my question once I go and figure out how to do that.